# Grid puzzle where player can't restep on tiles - Processing

Tags: processing

Same concept as the Sootopolis Gym in Pokemon Sapphire/Ruby/Emerald, i.e. once a tile has been stepped on, it changes colour and if all tiles have been stepped on, you clear the puzzle; however if your character steps on it again, the tile breaks and the level resets.

Here's what I have in my level function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < icePuzzle1.length; i++) { 
  for (int j = 0; j < icePuzzle1.length; j++) {
    //Sets colour to cyan
    fill(0, 255, 255);

    //Changes corresponding boolean when stepped on
    if (characterPosX == i*rectWidth && characterPosY == j*rectWidth) {
      stepped[i][j] = true;
    }

    //Changes colour if stepped on
    if (stepped[i][j] == true) {
      fill(255);
    }

    //Tile details
    stroke(100, 100, 100, 30);
    rect(i*rectWidth, j*rectWidth, rectWidth, rectWidth);
  }
}
```

I tried adding this

`if (characterPosX == i*rectWidth && characterPosY == j*rectWidth){
   characterPosX = 0;
   characterPosY = 0;
   }`

under `if (stepped[i][j] == true)`, which makes my character immediately teleport to the start whenever it steps onto the maze's tiles.

How do I change it so that as long as he doesn't restep on the stepped tiles he can keep walking through the maze?

Edit: Having a hard time trying to figure out how to check if all the tiles have been stepped on as well. Tried using this

```
boolean allValuesInArrayAreTrue = true;
boolean [][] sth = {{false,false,false},{false,false,true}};
for(int i = 0; i < sth.length; i++) {
for (int k = 0; k < sth[i].length; k++) {
    if(!sth[i][k]) {
        allValuesInArrayAreTrue = false;
    }
}
```

}

but it returns true as long as the last tile (most bottom right) has been stepped on, regardless if it was stepped on first or last.

I've been at this for 3 days trying out different approaches but nothing's been working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Since managed to figure this part out by setting a counter for each tile, and implementing the if(stepped){ trigger reset} in keypressed().

Answer (score 0):

Try this concept:
Start all blocks on true, as in the player can still step on them.
Have a counter for each block set to zero.
If player steps on block and the counter is at zero, the counter for that block goes up to one.
Then when the player steps off the block and the counter is at one, the counter goes to two and sets the block to false meaning that the if the player steps on that block again, the level resets. 
When the level resets, reset all blocks to true and set all counters to zero. For beating the game, check for if every block is set to false.